# Posición máxima y posición mínima de un vector en Python

Tags: python

Buenas a todos,

Me gustaría saber como teniendo por ejemplo este vector--> `a=[0,88,1,451,652,123,51]` hacer un código que me pusiese que la posición del número máximo en este vector es la `4`.

He probado con `np.where(max())` pero es que no me da un número como resultado me da esto `(array([4]),)`
 y no me sirve para implementarlo en mi código.

¿Alguien sabe?

Muchas gracias, saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logicamente se puede implementar de muchas formas, y si tu vector es muy grande o necesitas mucho rendimiento puede haber soluciones mejores que otras pero te planteo una muy sencilla:

```
max_position = a.index(max(a))
min_position = a.index(min(a))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es justo lo que buscaba :)

Comment: En realidad, las funciones que buscas son `np.argmax` y `np.argmin` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html

Answer (score 1):

Otras formas serían partiendo de los datos:

```
a=[0,88,1,451,652,123,51]

# Reeditando la solución que no te servía ya que te devolvía una tupla y ahora un integer

import numpy as np
a = np.array(a)
indice_max = int(np.where(a==max(a))[0])
indice_min = int(np.where(a==min(a))[0])

# Con numpy:

import numpy as np
a = np.array    
indice_max = a.argmax()
indice_min = a.argimn()

# Compresion de listas, util si el máximo se repite y necesitas ambos indices...

maximo = max(a)
indice_max =[i for i, j in enumerate(a) if j == maximo]

minimo = min(a)
indice_min =[i for i, j in enumerate(a) if j == minimo]

#enumerate y funcion lambda

indice_max = max(enumerate(a), key=(lambda x: x[1]))
indice_min = min(enumerate(a), key=(lambda x: x[1]))
```